# Weighted importance sampling (WIS) and Importance sampling (IS)

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, model-evaluation, artificial-intelligence, importance-sampling

I am currently reading papers about off-policy evaluation (or counterfactual evaluation) of reinforcement learning policies, including ones about the doubly robust estimator.

As in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03493, many papers say that "the weighted importance sampling (WIS) estimator or its stepwise (per-reward) version is considered more practical than the importance sampling (IS) estimator or its stepwise (per-reward) version, especially where being biased is not crucial". I understand this is true because WIS has lower variance than IS even though it is biased (it is consistent though).

But what I am curious about is exactly when or where the bias of WIS becomes crucial so that the IS estimator can perform better than WIS.

Could you give any example scenario when this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of where an importance sampling (IS) estimator can be used to estimate a country's domestic spending. Assume a poor country where a large percent of the population do not have bank accounts. Further, you are given access to spending data for those with accounts to develop figures for the nation as a whole. This would clearly represent closely the actual countries spending pattern, but because of the precise impact of unreported cash income and differing spending among those without bank accounts, this is not expected to an unbiased estimate of the countries actual total domestic spending.

The large size weighting of those with bank accounts clearly still makes it superior, albeit distorted, over the sampling variance expected in a simple random strategy (SRS) scheme. However, a one time SRS could suggest a proper bias correction factor. So, now we have a superior 'weighted importance sampling (WIS) estimator'.

As to when the bias of WIS becomes problematic, assume an event, like a pandemic disease, that significantly disrupts spending patterns mostly in the cash society. Now, a recent IS estimator likely more closely reflects the true level in domestic spending versus a WIS estimator that is based on an outdated weighting factor.